# Using AIML with PHP

Tags: php, aiml

Simply, can I use AIML with PHP? And if yes, then how can I do that?.

I have tried search it on google but I could not find results that helped.

Comment: It kind of depends on what you mean "use".  The top few results searching for `aiml php` bring up a few chat bots written in PHP.  Perhaps you could examine one of those?  If you had another definition of "use", you'll need to clarify.  (Personally I've just taken to running the basic Java implementation in the background and querying it through HTTP.)

Comment: I have tried Program-O, examined it and i can't understand it.

Comment: OKay, fair enough.  Could you explain what, exactly, you're trying to do or accomplish?

Comment: I am making a chat bot like Program-O

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is absolutely possible.

[Program O](http://blog.program-o.com/) would be a good way to start making bot without inventing the wheel again, Program O is an AIML interpretor written in PHP, and uses a MySQL database to store
chatbot information, including the AIML files used to formulate the chatbot's responses.

You can get it on [gitHub](https://github.com/Program-O/Program-O) too